# How to map Duration type with JPA

Tags: jpa, time, types, annotations, duration

I have a property field in a class that is of type `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`.  It basically represents a time span (e.g. 4 hours and 34 minutes).

JPA is telling me it is an invalid type, which doesn't shock me.

Whats a good solution this?  I could implement my own Duration class, but I don't know how to get JPA to "accept" it as a datatype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Whats a good solution this? I could implement my own Duration class, but I don't know how to get JPA to "accept" it as a datatype.

JPA does not support custom types so if you want to go this way you'll have to use a JPA extension from your provider. For example, Hibernate allows to define [custom value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom) that you declare with [`@Type`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794). Obviously, this will harm portability between providers which might be a concern. If not, then you know it is doable.

With standard JPA, the traditional approach would be to add another getter/setter pair which adapt the problematic property and perform conversion when accessed. I would use a `Long` to store a duration:

```
public MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private javax.xml.datatype.Duration duration;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Long getDurationAsJpaCompatibleType() {
        return MyXmlUtil.convertDurationToLong(this.duration);
    }
    public void setDurationAsJpaCompatibleType(Long duration) {
        setDuration(MyXmlUtil.convertLongToDuration(duration));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror the exact fields in the Duration class into your own custom class, but that might be overkill...I'm assuming you don't need that kind of duration flexibility/granularity.

So pick the fields you want, add them to your class, mark the class with the @Embeddable annotation, and add the proper JPA annotations to the fields (which I'm assuming will be simple ints).

In your entity that will store a duration, add the @Embedded annotation to the field or getter, whichever you typically use.  From here you can further tweak the column definitions with @AttributeOverride.

Comment: Are you saying to wrap the Duration class or implement a new one from scratch?

Comment: Creating your own from scratch would be easiest.  The javax.xml.datatype.Duration class has more fields then you probably want to expose as columns in your DB table, so create a custom Duration object with just the time granularity that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [joda-time hibernate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate). Refer to the [available types](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html#Available_Types) that can be persisted. You could then use the [joda Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) in the following way:

```
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDuration")
private Duration startDateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a java.time.Duation field which is converted via a javax.persistence.AttributeConverter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DurationAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, Integer> {

  @Override
  public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration pX) {
    if (pX == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return (int) pX.toMinutes();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Duration convertToEntityAttribute(Integer pY) {
    if (pY == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Duration.ofMinutes(pY);
    }
  }
}
```

The Duration Object is mapped to a number column, which stores the duration in minutes.