# Incompatible argument to function in JPA with JAXB types

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb

As explained here: [How to map Duration type with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830089/how-to-map-duration-type-with-jpa)

I have the same code and jaxb is generating the getter and setter wrapper:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "VALUEITEM", length = 127)
public String getValueItem() {
    return XmlAdapterUtils.unmarshall(DurationAsString.class, this.getValue());
}

public void setValueItem(String target) {
    setValue(XmlAdapterUtils.marshall(DurationAsString.class, target));
}
```

but when trying to persist an object I got:

```
method: pcgetValueItem signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Incompatible argument to function
```

on every wrapper field.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into a similar issue with Hyperjaxb-generated classes inside an OSGi container.

Answer (score 1):

Reason (almost always) for java.lang.VerifyError with such an message is that you compiled against different version of class than you are running. This means that there is likely two versions of getValueItem around - one with matching signature and other one without.

Most often this problem is of course faced with external libraries - compiling against newer and running with older, for example.

Just clean trash, rebuild everything and maybe you will find out compile time error instead or in best case problem is solved right away.

Comment: Could it be that the enhancement I am making for JPA are causing this? I did a clean but issue is still happening.