# Parsing and storing local times

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa

I am converting some CSV tables to entries in a PostgreSQL server using the Java Persistence API. I am running into some trouble because one column contains data which is almost but not quite corresponding to a local time: Often entries are like `09:33:00` which I could obviously parse into a LocalTime. However, sometimes the time exceeds 24 hours like so: `25:01:00`. The values describe the seconds since midnight but they are not constrained to be in the range `00:00:00 - 23:59:59`. In order to compare these values it is unavoidable to somehow store whether or not a day has passed.

I was wondering about the correct way to parse and store these values. Is it a good idea to use `java.time.Duration` or is this a case for `java.util.Date`?

Comment: In which calendar is there a 25th hour?!

Comment: Well, technically it is a duration.... The data describes a set of time intervals which overlap and wrap around...

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830089/how-to-map-duration-type-with-jpa